# Elasticsearch : IllegalArgumentException

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I have used the below query to match all docs

```
{
 "query": {
    "custom_score": {
       "query": {
          "query_string": {
                 "query": "*"
           }
     },
    "script": "_score"
  }
 }
}
```

But unfortunately i'm getting the below error

```
{
  "took": 1515,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 7,
    "successful": 6,
    "failed": 1,
    "failures": [
      {
    "status": 500,
    "reason": "RemoteTransportException[[els][inet[/192.168.1.226:9300]][search/phase/fetch/id]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[docID must be >= 0 and < maxDoc=53134 (got docID=214747)]; "
      }
    ]
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1574502,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [

    ]
  }
}
```

NOTE: Im using 0.90.3 es version and this cluster using four nodes

And im only getting this issue in 0.90.3.

Is there any solution to prevent this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Really interesting error, might be a bug. I would love to know more about it. Can you reproduce it consistently? Only with that very same query? Do all the four nodes use the same elasticsearch version (and same java version, including patch)?

Comment: Also, would be great to have a look at the complete stacktrace from your elasticsearch log.

Comment: @javanna : the four nodes use same es version(0.90.3),java(1.7.0_25), patch.  And i'm getting only this error in rest call. no error in es log

Comment: i found that if i assign any value to _script then it is working fine. i think there is some issue in calculating score by lucene itself.

Comment: It might be a issue with using nest objects?

Comment: Don't know yet what it could be. Would be great to be able to reproduce it. Could you share your data directory with me? How big is it?

Comment: @javanna it has 20gb of data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that it will necessarily solve your problem, but to match all documents, you should use a [match all query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/match-all-query/).

```
"custom_score": {
  "query": {
    "match_all" : { }
  },
  "script": "_score"
}
```